# HTMLUNIT 2.9 jar posting comments

Tags: java, post, comments, htmlunit, htmlcontrols

I wrote this code:

```
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.BrowserVersion;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlForm;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlSubmitInput;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlTextArea;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
*
* @author user
*/
public class YouTubeComment {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean f = YouTubeLogin.login();
    try {
        if (f) {
            WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_3_6);
            webClient.setRedirectEnabled(true);
            webClient.setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
            HtmlPage firstPage = webClient.getPage("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kqDacBDoVM4&feature=related");
            List<HtmlForm> forms = new ArrayList();
            forms = (List<HtmlForm>) firstPage.getForms();
            HtmlForm form = firstPage.getForms().get(1);

            HtmlTextArea commentArea = (HtmlTextArea)form.getTextAreaByName("comment");
            commentArea.setText("good");
         HtmlSubmitInput submitButton =(HtmlSubmitInput)form.getInputByName("");
            HtmlPage pageAfterPost = (HtmlPage) submitButton.click();
        } else {
            System.out.println("Sorry..! Login is not successful");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

This application can login to a YouTube account with the username and password.
I want to write some code for posting comments after the successful login.
Please Help.

Comment: Could you at least post the URL where you want to post a comment?

Comment: @Guillaume Polet,http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kqDacBDoVM4&feature=related

Comment: Forgive me for asking, but is there some valid reason you want to do this? I'm afraid to offer help if this is just a giant spam engine.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so you should probably try to look at the HTML content of the page with Firebug on Firefox to see what are the fields to use to post a comment.

From what I've seen, you need to find a div called 'comments-view'. A bit deepers in that div, there is a form with an action `/comment_servlet?add_comment=1`. Then you should fill in the textarea comment (it has its name attribute set to 'comment'). Eventually, you need to find the "Publish" button and click on it.

Comment: by writing this code:

HtmlForm form = firstPage.getFormByName("/comment_servlet?add_comment=1");

its throwing an exception,

com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ElementNotFoundException: elementName=[form] attributeName=[name] attributeValue=[/comment_servlet?add_comment=1]
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.getFormByName(HtmlPage.java:562)
        at htmlunitexample.YouTubeComment.main(YouTubeComment.java:32)

Comment: the form does not have a name, it only as an action and class which is not sufficient to find it. What you can do is find the div with id 'comments-view' and inside find the form, using `getHtmlElementsByTagName` (there should be only one)